# Calculating convolution-type integral in xarray or Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, dask, python-xarray

I have the following integral to calculate:

[image]

where `H(.)` is the [Heaviside function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.heaviside.html).

Now, I know how to iterate manually over the array and calculate `I` this way, but I obviously would like to it from xarray or at the very least numpy to take advantage of the speed-ups.

One huge complication here is that my datasets are huge and I have to chunk in time to be able to treat them. But I'm failing even before getting there.

For example, I'm trying to start with an array that depends only on `x`, `y` and `z` in the MWE below, but I'm still getting an error when calling `get_z_star()` because apparently `xr.apply_ufunc` is passing a numpy array instead of a DataArray, which is what I want:

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
b_tot = xr.DataArray(np.random.randn(10,10,10,10), dims=('x', 'y', 'z', 't'), coords=dict(x=x,
                                                                                          y=x,
                                                                                          z=x,
                                                                                          t=x))
def get_H_func_int(b, b_prime):
    """ b needs to be a float
        b_prime needs to be a DataArray but can't depend on time
    """
    H_func = np.heaviside(b_prime-b, 1/2)
    return H_func.integrate(('x', 'y', 'z'))
    
def get_z_star(b, b_prime, **kwargs):
    """ b here can be an dataArray but can't depend on time
        b_prime needs to be a DataArray but can't depend on time
    """
    I = xr.apply_ufunc(get_H_func_int, b, b_prime, **kwargs)
    return I
    
b = b_tot.min()
b_prime = b_tot.isel(t=0)
print(get_H_func_int(b, b_prime))
print(get_z_star(b_prime, b_prime))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `xarray.apply_ufunc` is built specifically for wrapping functions that take either raw NumPy or dask arrays as inputs, so that you can apply them to DataArrays.  At least from the perspective of this minimal example, is there any reason that `get_H_func_int` will not do the job on its own?  It can already take DataArrays as inputs and appropriately return a DataArray -- eagerly or lazily -- so it is not immediately clear why `apply_ufunc` is needed.  There may be more to your actual problem, however, that I am not seeing.

Comment: I was trying to use `apply_ufunc` because `get_H_func_int` only works if `b` is a scalar. If I try to make it work for a `DataArray` `xarray` just broadcasts everything and doesn't really do what I want. But perhaps you have a good point that I can try to modify it so that it does works for `DataArrays` without the need to be wrapped in `apply_ufunc`...